Is $\mathbb{F}_2^n/ rs(H)$ the same as the kernel of $H$?
I am not very familiar with quotient spaces but I am trying to understand what the authors of this paper mean in Lemma 1. Specifically, for a binary parity check matrix $H$, they consider the object
$$ker(H)\otimes \left[\mathbb{F}_2^n/rs(H)\right]$$
$rs$ refers to the row space of $H$. It seems that $\mathbb{F}_2^n/rs(H)$ just the kernel of $H$? Since the authors did not say $ker(H)\otimes ker(H)$, I guess I am missing something. What is
$$ker(H)\otimes \left[\mathbb{F}_2^n/rs(H)\right]?$$


Explicit example:
Let
$$H = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 &0\end{pmatrix}.$$
The kernel of $H$ is the one dimensional subspace with basis vector
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
I have that
$$\mathbb{F}_n^2/rs(H) = \Bigg\{\Big\{(0,0,0), (0,1,1), (1,1,0), (1,0,1)\Big\}, \Big\{(1,1,1), (1,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0)\Big\} \Bigg\}$$
I just pick the representative element from each coset namely $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$. The vector space formed by these elements is precisely $ker(H)$. Where exactly did I go wrong?
